# Bootstrap columns misalignment on Safari

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, favicon

I have 3 Bootstrap columns of width 4 (col-4), each containing a favicon. On Chrome and IE alignment is fine, however on Safari the columns seem to be shifted to the right for some reason.

[image: Safari:]

[image: Chrome:]

Here's my code:

```
<div class = "container-fluid padding">
<div class = "row text-center padding">
    <div class = "col-12">
        <h1>Connect</h1>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4 social">
        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com/dsc.uwa" target = "_blank"><i class = "fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4 social">
        <a href = "https://www.linkedin.com/company/dscuwa/about" target = "_blank"><i class = "fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-4 social">
        <a href = "https://www.instagram.com/dscuwa/" target = "_blank"><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing interesting going on with the CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was the above `col-12` that was pushing it. I ended up changing it to `col-md-12` and it fixed it for me. This might only be a work around but it helped me so hopefully it will help you.